ML.Net no zip file for AddPredictionEnginePool
New to ML.Net. Have created a model directly in my API and want to create a Pool using the AddPredictionEnginePool so I can multithread the predictions. However all the documentation says there is a .zip file that I should reference, but I do not see one. Should use the .mlnet file instead or is there a way to directly reference the object? Or is there a step where I need to request a zip file when generating the model?
Here is an example of what the suggest, note the .FromFile is what I am trying to populate:
builder.Services.AddPredictionEnginePool<ModelInput, ModelOutput>().FromFile(modelName: "MyModel", filePath: "where_is_this_zip_file.zip", watchForChanges: true);

UPDATE
So have made a little more progress. In looking for the Zip file, I rename the MyModel.mlnet file to MyModel.Zip. Looks as though it is the zip file I was looking for (???):

And the contents. Does this look right?

Next in the program.cs file, I verified I have the correct pathing, by loading the .zip file and viewed it in the debugger. It was there. And then I used the AddPredictionEnginePool as follows:
ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open("D:\\MyCompany\\MyApp\\MyService.ApiService\\MyModel.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read);
builder.Services.AddPredictionEnginePool<ModelInput, ModelOutput>()
            .FromFile(modelName: "MyModel", filePath: "D:\\MyCompany\\MyApp\\MyService.ApiService\\MyModel.zip",
            watchForChanges: true);

When I run that code, AddPredictionEnginePool, there is no error thrown, but when I look thru the list of services I do not see it (maybe it has a strange name???).
Then I inject the pool in my controller as follows:
public class ModelController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly PredictionEnginePool<ModelInput, ModelOutput> _predictionEnginePool;

public ModelController(PredictionEnginePool<ModelInput, ModelOutput> predictionEnginePool)
{
    _predictionEnginePool = predictionEnginePool;
}

When attempting to use it as follows:
var testprediction = _predictionEnginePool.Predict(testInput);

I get the following error:
'You need to configure a default, not named, model before you use this method.'

My thoughts are that either the EnginePool does not work or the .mlnet is not consumable by the AddPredictionEnginePool, Or am I missing a step to set it as the default model? I still have not found an actual working example of the Pool being used, just fragments.

The solution, finally, is pretty simple (though not documented anywhere I could find). You have to ask for the model by name, in my case:
            PredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput> engineByName = _predictionEnginePool.GetPredictionEngine("MyModel");
            var prediction = engineByName.Predict(inputData);

So in the end, the MyModel.mlnet file needed to be renamed to MyModel.zip, and then the above code will work. Although I have not tried just using the MyModel.mlnet file directly - it probably would work

Firstly you should have data to train with. Then you get "trained model" which can be saved to a zip file using
mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, data.Schema, "model.zip");

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/save-load-machine-learning-models-ml-net

Been using the ML Builder to build and train the model. That does not output a zip file. To use the PredictionEnginePool do I need to abandon using the Builder? Or is there a setting in the Builder to generate the .zip file? I am able to call for a single prediction currently, only it is not thread safe. Thx!
